# FlexSlider / Dazzling Theme - Bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have an issue with Dazzling Theme for Wordpress : On Google Chrome, when I reload my homepage (with F5), content is hidden by flexslider element. If I look in html/css I can see that :

```html
<div class="flexslider" style="height: 0px;">
element.style { height: 0px; }
```

I resize my page (or click anywhere on) and I can see that :

element.style { height: 538px; }

I investigated and I think the solution is in flexslider.css

But I do not know what I should modify.

Answer (score 0):

```
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
```

or

```
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}
```

should be modified on flexslider.css

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to custom css or child theme style.css:

div.flexslider {height: 100% !important;}

Answer (score -1):

It works for me to modify with

```
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: auto !important;}
```

on `flexslider.css`